# Read a list from txt file in Python

Tags: python, list, file

I need to read a list from a txt file and import as a list variable into my .py file.
I could use the import function, but the program must be compiled and when it's compiled to an exe, all the imports ends converted into a non-modificable files, so the solution is to read from a txt.
The code that I use is similar to this

First, I got my list in a txt file like this:

```
[['preset1','a1','b1'],['preset2','a2','b2'],['preset3','a3','b3'],['preset4','a4','b4']]
```

Then, I read the list in python:

```
file = open('presets.txt','r')
content = file.readline()
newpresets = content.split("'")
file.close()
```

And I supposed that with the split function to delete the ' symbols, the program take the content as a list and not as a string but this not works...
So, I need how to read the content of the file and not interpretate as a string.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `ast.literal_eval` :

```
>>> a = str([['preset1','a1','b1'],['preset2','a2','b2'],['preset3','a3','b3'],['preset4','a4','b4']])
>>> a
"[['preset1', 'a1', 'b1'], ['preset2', 'a2', 'b2'], ['preset3', 'a3', 'b3'], ['preset4', 'a4', 'b4']]"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
[['preset1', 'a1', 'b1'], ['preset2', 'a2', 'b2'], ['preset3', 'a3', 'b3'], ['preset4', 'a4', 'b4']]
>>>
```

Comment: Having reading the comments and understand the real use of the eval() function, I prefer to use this... Cause eval() is very insecure, this only interpretates my string as a list, I think...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval